# Checking if an email exists in another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm doing an **registration** form and I'm trying to check if the email that the person inserts in the input is already in another table that has all emails that I allow to be registered. If it is it should register the person. I don't understand where I'm failing. I'm starting now with php. Please help.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['signup-submit'])){


    require 'dbh.inc.php';

    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uid']);
    $email =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['mail']);
    $password =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['pwd']);
    $passwordRepeat =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd-repeat']);
    $check1 = $_POST['check1'];
    $check2 = $_POST['check2'];
    if(empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($password) || empty($passwordRepeat)) {

        header ("Location: ../header.php?error=emptyfields&uid=".$username."&mail=".$email);
        exit();
    }
    else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && !preg_match("/^[a-zA-z0-9]*$/", $username)){

        header("Location: ../header.php?error=invalidadmail&uid=");
        exit();
    } 
    else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){

        header("Location: ../header.php?error=invalidadmail&uid=".$username);
        exit();
    } 
    else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-z0-9]*$/", $username)){

        header("Location: ../header.php?error=invalidaduid&mail=".$email);
    exit();

}
    elseif($password !== $passwordRepeat){
        header("Location: ../header.php?error=passwordcheck&uid=".$username."&mail=".$email);
        exit();
    }
    elseif((!isset($check1)) || (!isset($check2))){
        echo"<script>alert('É necessário confirmar as duas opções :(');
        window.location.href='../header.php'</script>";
exit();
    }
```

This is the part of the code that is not **working**

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM emails WHERE (email_socio = '$email')";
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2); 

if (mysqli_num_rows($res) < 0) {
echo "FAIL";
}
```

These are other validations and where it will insert the data into final table

```
    else{


$sql = "SELECT uidUsers FROM users WHERE uidUsers=?";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
    header("Location: ../header.php?error=sqlerror");
    exit();

}
 else{
     mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username);
     mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
     mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
     $resultCheck = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
     if($resultCheck > 0){
        header("Location: ../header.php?error=usertaken&mail=".$email);
        exit();
     }
     else {




        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (uidUsers, emailUsers, pwdUsers) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
            header("Location: ../header.php?error=sqlerror");
            exit();

        } else {
            $hashedPwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $username, $email, $hashedPwd);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $sql ="SELECT * FROM users WHERE uidUsers='$username' AND emailUsers='$email'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    $userid = $row['idUsers'];
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO profileimg (userid, status) VALUES ('$userid', 1)";
                    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                }
            }
            header("Location: ../header.php?signup=success");
            exit();
        }
     }
 }
 }
 mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
 mysqli_close($conn);
}

else {
    header("Location: ../header.php");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by failing? What errors are you getting, if any? What is the actual result (does it register everyone)? Also, do you really mean in another *database*, not another *table*?

Comment: I'm sorry, it is in another table. I corrected it now. This code just keeps registering any email, it doesn't just register the ones that are in the other table.

Comment: You need to pare down the code you post to only what demonstrates the error. There's too much unrelated code here for anyone to know what is or isn't relevant.

Comment: Why aren't you using a prepared statement for everything?

Comment: If you want to check if a record exists, the `if (mysqli_num_rows($res) < 0)` should be using `>` and not `<`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition is wrong:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($res) < 0) {
    echo "FAIL";
}
```

You're checking for *less than zero*, when in fact it should be *less than one*.

So, change it to either of the two:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($res) === 0) // it logically cannot contain negative values
if (mysqli_num_rows($res) < 1)
```